# Decrypted data with usage of TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider has additonal characters

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, tripledes

I am facing with problem when decrypting data with usage of TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider. The problem is that decrypted value contains beside of original value some additional, strange characters at the end

Per instance if I provide "rastko" to be encrypted, I will get later with decryption something like this "rastko⥊㮶". For other values it could be different number of 'dummy' characters or in some cases I will get exact value.

Then, I saw that for all encrypted data byte array size is divisible by 8. It looks like any provided data is rounded on value that is divisible by 8. Only in case when original encoded value is divisible by 8, decryption will retrieve appropriate value.

Here are methods that I am using :

```
        public static byte[] EncryptPassword(string password, out byte[] cryptoKey, out byte[] cryptoIV)
    {
        try
        {
            UnicodeEncoding unicodeEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] unicodePassword = unicodeEncoding.GetBytes(password);
            byte[] encryptedPassword;

            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                tripleDes.Key = GetCryptoKey();
                tripleDes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                tripleDes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                cryptoKey = tripleDes.Key;
                cryptoIV = tripleDes.IV;

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = tripleDes.CreateEncryptor();

                    using (
                        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(unicodePassword, 0, unicodePassword.Length);
                        ////cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }

                    encryptedPassword = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return encryptedPassword;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Password encryption failed !", ex);
        }
    }

    public static string DecryptPassword(byte[] encryptedPassword, byte[] cryptoKey, byte[] cryptoIV)
    {
        try
        {
            UnicodeEncoding unicodeEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
            string readablePassword;

            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                tripleDes.Key = cryptoKey;
                tripleDes.IV = cryptoIV;
                tripleDes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                tripleDes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                // Create a new MemoryStream using the passed 
                // array of encrypted data.
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedPassword))
                {
                    // Create crypto transform that defines the basic operations of cryptographic transformations.
                    ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = tripleDes.CreateDecryptor();

                    // Create a CryptoStream using the MemoryStream and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
                    using (CryptoStream decryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        decryptoStream.Write(encryptedPassword, 0, encryptedPassword.Length);
                        ///decryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }

                    byte[] decryptedPassword = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    //Convert the buffer into a string and return it.
                    readablePassword = unicodeEncoding.GetString(decryptedPassword, 0, decryptedPassword.Length);
                }
            }

            return readablePassword;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Password decryption failed !", ex);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] GetCryptoKey()
    {
        UnicodeEncoding unicodeEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        string plainKey = "rastkoisajev2310982josipasenera153";
        byte[] encodedKey = unicodeEncoding.GetBytes(plainKey);

        // Prepares 192 bit key
        byte[] preparedKey = new byte[24];
        Array.Copy(encodedKey, preparedKey, 24);

        return preparedKey;
    }
```

Here is sample test invocation :

```
       private static void CryptoTest()
    {
        string password = "rastko";

        byte[] cryptoKey;
        byte[] cryptoIV;

        byte[] encryptedPassword = Crypto.EncryptPassword(password, out cryptoKey, out cryptoIV);

        string decryptedPAssword = Crypto.DecryptPassword(encryptedPassword, cryptoKey, cryptoIV);
    }
```

I have not good experience with security. What I see is that IV vector is 8byte size and as I found it is related to BlockSize, that is 8times greater then IV size. TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider for IV vector is using 8byte value. I can not change this.

Could you please tell me what I have to do or did I wrote something wrongly ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Rastko.

Comment: 1) Encrypting passwords is rarely a good choice. Are you sure you want to encrypt it, and not hash it? 2) Why 3DES  and not AES? Is this a legacy application?

Comment: Hi @CodesInChaos ,
1.) Encryption is only one of the options beside of hashing. It will enable easy choosing option - use encryption or use hashing or something else
2.) You are right for this. I have found that AES is much secure algorithm then this one. I am planning to additional Crypto provider with this logic. TripleDES was my first solution. No, application is a new one, it is not legacy.

Comment: "It will enable easy choosing option" That doesn't make much sense. I can't think of any situation in which easy switching between encryption and hashing is useful. In situations in which password encryption makes sense, password hashing isn't even possible, and it situations where password hashing is possible, encrypting it is stupid, since it unnecessarily weakens your system *a lot*. Figure out which one you need, and use that one.

Comment: Thank you @CodesInChaos I will consider your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After detail investigation I have found the solution for my problem.
I have changed a little bit decryption logic.

Instead of this part in DecryptPassword method :

```
 // Create a CryptoStream using the MemoryStream and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
                using (CryptoStream decryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    decryptoStream.Write(encryptedPassword, 0, encryptedPassword.Length);
                    ///decryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                }

                byte[] decryptedPassword = memoryStream.ToArray();

                //Convert the buffer into a string and return it.
                readablePassword = unicodeEncoding.GetString(decryptedPassword, 0, decryptedPassword.Length);
            }
```

I am now using the Read logic from CryptoStream and then I am just removing nullable characters. It is like this now :

```
                        // Create a CryptoStream using the MemoryStream and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
                    using (CryptoStream decryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        // Create buffer to hold the decrypted data.
                        byte[] fromEncrypt = new byte[encryptedPassword.Length];

                        decryptoStream.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);

                        //Convert the buffer into a string and return it.
                        readablePassword = unicodeEncoding.GetString(fromEncrypt);
                        readablePassword = readablePassword.Replace("\0", string.Empty);
                    }
```

This works perfectly for me ! Thank you all for your time.

Comment: It must be me, but why do streams move both ways in .net? I would just not have thought of that being a problem. Glad you solved it Rastko.

Answer (score 1):

DES is a 64 bit block cypher.  Any text that does not divide cleanly into 64 bit (=8 byte) blocks needs to be padded to make up a whole number of blocks.  You need to set padding for encryption and decryption.  If you have control of both ends then use PKCS#5 padding to encrypt and decrypt.  If you only have control over the decryption end, then ask the encrypting end what padding they are using and expect that.

Comment: He appears to be already doing just that with the line `tripleDes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  My error.  It may be that the plaintext is being padded twice.  The PKCS#7 is being removed and some other padding (?random?) is being left.  If the other padding always leaves a multiple of 8 bytes then that is the first place to look.  The last byte/s of a random padding may give the length so it can be removed correctly.

Comment: Nah, my bet is still on the padding not happening because he forgot to flush...that does not sound right for some reason.

Comment: In both cases encryption and decryption I am using PaddingMode.PKCS7 padding that is default for TripleDes. As you can see I have commented FlushFinalBlock method. With it, it was same and I have found on 
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock.aspx)
that Close method of CryptoStream will implicitly call this method. Because it is under using block in my code, I am OK with that.

From your comments and internet documents I see that it is performing kind of rounding on 8bytes. That looks like a problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Note that encrypting a password is normally not the way to go. Use [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) instead. Don't confuse passwords and keys!*

Try to make sure that your CryptoStreams get closed or flushed:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock.aspx

If you don't then the padding/unpadding will likely not be performed, and you get trash instead.

Comment: I am using default PaddingMode.PKCS7 for TripleDes seevice provider. As you can see I have using blocks, so every IDisposable object is closed properly in methods.  I will consider also PBKDF2 that you have sent to me. Thank you